# Find Element Within XML Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml file with details of around 100 maps, sample below:

```
<mapdata>
    <record>
        <id>1974</id>
        <title>Hong Kong, Kowloon and the New Territories</title>
        <scale>1 to 100,000</scale>
        <note>Black and white map of the territory</note>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>1974.1</id>
        <title>Hong Kong, Kowloon and the New Territories (HM50C)</title>
        <scale>1 to 50,000</scale>
        <note>Hong Kong, Kowloon and the New Territories</note>
    </record> 
</mapdata>
```

Knowing the `<id>` I need to extract the details from the remaining elements `<title> <scale> <note>`

The code I have developed is:

```
var xhrm= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrm.onload = function(){
if (xhrm.status === 200) {
        var objxml = xhrm.responseXML;
        
        sr0 = $(objxml).find("mapdata record:has(id:contains('" + sref + "')) title").text();
        sr1 = $(objxml).find("mapdata record:has(id:contains('" + sref + "')) scale").text();
        sr2 = $(objxml).find("mapdata record:has(id:contains('" + sref + "')) note").text();
    
        console.log("Title: " + sr0);
        console.log("Scale: " + sr1);
        console.log("Notes: " + sr2);
    }}

    xhrm.open("GET","mapdata.xml",true);
    xhrm.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", "\"doesnt-match-anything\"");
    xhrm.send(null);
```

However, with this approach using jQuery, `id:contains` does not select a unique value as it is true for '1974' and '1974.1'. Is there a simple fast way to I locate an exact match and identify the sibling details?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter(function)` instead to do an absolute match.

Something like:

```
var $record = $(objxml).find('record').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('id').text() === '1974'
});

console.log($record.find('title').text())
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Once more unto the breach of javascript :)